# if $A \in C^{2015,2015}$ and $rank(A) < 1000$ proof that $\dim(\ker(A+A^T)) > 15$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I want to solve that thesis: 
if $A \in C^{2015,2015}$ and $rank(A) < 1000$ proof that $\dim(\ker(A+A^T)) > 15 $

from the fact that $$\dim(im(A)) = \dim(im(A^T))$$ and
$$ \dim(\ker(A))+\dim(im(A))=n $$
it follows that 
$$\dim(\ker(A)) = \dim(\ker(A^T))$$ 
We know that $rank(A) < 1000$. Hence $\dim(\ker(A))>1015$
But there I have stuck...
thanks for your time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're one line from the solution:

You showed that $\dim (\ker A) > 1015$ (so $A$ sends a vector space of dimension $1015$ to zero).

Moreover since $\dim (Im A ) = \dim (Im A^T)$ you also have that the dimensions of the kernels equal and so $\dim(\ker A^T)>1015$.

Therefore by the dimensions theorem we have that the dimension of $\ker A \cap \ker A^T$ is at least $15$ (because $\dim(\ker A + \ker A^T)\leq 2015$). This completes the proof, because $\ker (A+A^T)$ contains $\ker A\cap \ker A^T$.

Comment: Sorry if it is stupid question but I am sitting and I have no idea why $ \dim(\ker A + \ker A^T)\leq 2015$. Could I ask you for an explanation?

Comment: @VirtualUser Both $\ker A$ and $\ker A^T$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^{2015}$. Therefore so is their sum.

Comment: "Therefore by the dimensions theorem we have that the dimension of $\ker A \cap \ker A^T$ is at least $15$ (because $\dim(\ker A + \ker A^T)\leq 2015$)." Ok but how from dimensions theorem I get this proposal? Dimension theorem says that  $dim(im(T)) + dim(kernel(T)) = n $, but there, If we assume that T is $ \ker A + \ker A^T$ I haven't got  neither dim(im(T)) nor dim(kernel(T))

Comment: @VirtualUser This is the other dimension theorem. I'm talking about this $\dim (U+W) = \dim U + \dim W - \dim U\cap W$. Insert $U=\ker A$ and $W=\ker A^T$.

Comment: Aaah, now I understand, you deserve a lot of thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname {im}(A+A^t)=\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{im}A)+\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{im}A^t)-\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{im}A\cap\operatorname{im}A^t)\lt2000$.

Comment: No, using the hypothesis,  less than $1000+1000=2000$.